# How can i run my windows app with appcelerator?

Tags: windows-phone, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

i'm new at windows phone app. I'm trying to setup my appcelerator, i installed visual studio 2013 with window phone sdk like the appcelerator documentation say and all went well. After i write the classic hello world i saw that in my appcelerator there aren't the windows phone emulator. I searched on internet some information and now i think i can't use the simulator without pay a developer license. That's true? i can't test my app without a license?

I founded also that maybe i can run my app on only 1 device for free. That's true? I hope you can help me :) Thanks.

Comment: You can use the Windows Phone emulators without having to pay for a developer licence - but you do need hardware/operating system support for Hyper-V

Answer (score 0):

To build for a Windows Phone emulator, you need to obtain your Windows publisher ID. You can run windows app using the CLI command: **appc run -p windows**. Follow this guide [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Appcelerator_CLI_Tasks-section-43306725_AppceleratorCLITasks-WindowsPhoneEmulator) for details. And you don't have pay to use Windows phone emulator. Also refer to this [link](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2014/12/windows-platform-preview/) which might help you.

Comment: my problem is i can't find the publisher ID. And without it i can't do anything. When i go in my windows account where can i find it? I read on internet i need to go on dashboard, but when i went on dashboard Microsoft told me i need purchase the license. Or the ID is the email?

Comment: The instructions for getting a Publisher ID can be found here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Installing_the_Windows_Phone_SDK-section-43306274_InstallingtheWindowsPhoneSDK-ConfigurethePublisherID